# Can two different apps in apple app store with same app icon

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

**Can two different apps with the same app icon go live on the apple app store?**

Comment: yes. as long as their app name and package name is different

Comment: App name, Bundle identifier should not be same.

Comment: Decrease the size of the icon or something like that if you want it to be absolutely same icon

Answer (score 2):

I have apps that are accepted with the same icon but one app is rejected. 
To be safe, the answer is **NO**.

[image: Rejected]

Answer (score 0):

yes. as long as their app name and package name is different.
you just need to make sure their bundle IDs are different.

Comment: No, they cannot use same logo. It's copyright violation

Answer (score 0):

In my organization the old apps with same icon are there on app store but one year back I uploaded the two app with same icon then it was rejected.